# Cycle through combinations of 3 out of 5

Tags: python, arrays

I'm working on writing a poker simulation. I already got some parts ready.
But I stuck with comparing my hand with cards on the table.
My idea was to get my 2 cards and take 3 random cards from the deck and see if that makes a flush or something. But of course I have to cycle through so I take all combinations with my hand and the deck.

If these are the 5 cards from the deck and 1 represents the cards positions I will take and compare with. These are all combinations that I have to compare my cards with the deck.

```
00111
01011
01101
01110
10011
10101
10110
11001
11010
11100
```

How could I loop through this? The table cards are just an array of objects.

Comment: The cards are just of `0` and `1`? That doesn't sound like a poker.

Comment: No, the 0 or 1 is to visually tell those are the cards positions I will compare it to.

Comment: So you need all the combinations of 3 out of the 5 positions?

Comment: Is this Texas Hold'em? If so, then you don't need to pick 3 out of 5, but 5 out of 7. In any case, look at `itertools.combinations`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you have represented the output is confusing but since you want to select 3 cards from a set of 5 cards, you need 5C3. You can achieve this using `itertools.combinations`.

From the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) :-

**itertools.combinations(iterable, r)**:

> Return r length subsequences of elements from the input iterable.
>
> Combinations are emitted in lexicographic sort order. So, if the input
>   iterable is sorted, the combination tuples will be produced in sorted
>   order.
>
> Elements are treated as unique based on their position, not on their
>   value. So if the input elements are unique, there will be no repeat
>   values in each combination.

import itertools

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4]

print [p for p in itertools.combinations(a, 3)]
```

**Output:**

> `[(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 1, 4), (0, 2, 3), (0, 2, 4), (0, 3, 4),(1,2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]`

Answer (score 3):

Possibly try the `combinations` from `itertools`:

```
[c for c in itertools.combinations(range(5), 3)]

[(0, 1, 2),
 (0, 1, 3),
 (0, 1, 4),
 (0, 2, 3),
 (0, 2, 4),
 (0, 3, 4),
 (1, 2, 3),
 (1, 2, 4),
 (1, 3, 4),
 (2, 3, 4)]
```